# Generic Action call assignment issue

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, delegates

I need a way to setup properties on a form using generic calls. I have a static class that creates kind of singleton forms, a principal form (MDI) makes the call and the class takes care of the call, knowing either to show, open, etc.

Everything was going great till the moment I realized that I needed to set **properties** on the form. I can do it, but I want the assignment to occur **before the form load**.

I figured out a way to accomplish this, at least I thought I had had a cool idea, but... let's see the code:

```
    public interface IFormBase
    {
        Action<IFormBase> SetParameters { get; set; }
    }

    public class FormBase : Form, IFormBase
    {
        public Action<IFormBase> SetParameters { get; set; }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SetParameters != null)
            {
                SetParameters.Invoke(this);
            }
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }
    }
```

... later in the FormManager static class ...

```
        public TResult GetSingleTonForm<TResult, T>(object state, Action<T> setParameters)
            where TResult : FormBase
            where T : IFormBase
        {
            Type t = typeof(T);
            FormBase f = null;

            if (f == null)
            {
                f = (FormBase)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            }

            if (setParameters != null && f is IFormBase)
            {
                f.SetParameters = setParameters;
            }

            return (TResult)f;
        }
...
```

The problem:

> *Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Action<T>` to `System.Action<blabla.IFormBase>`*

I understand the error, I'm asking for help in order to elaborate a different solution maybe! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
public T GetSingleTonForm<T>(object state, Action<T> setParameters)
            where T : FormBase, IFormBase 
        {
            Type t = typeof(T);
            FormBase f = null;
            if (f == null)
            {
                 f = (FormBase)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            }

            if (setParameters != null && f is IFormBase)
            {
                setParameters.Invoke((T)f);
            }

            return (T)f;
        }
```

It does compile, and I think it does what you need. This way you won't need the `OnLoad` call on your `FormBase` either.